# DryIoC convention mapping how?

Tags: c#, ioc-container, dryioc

I want to set the DryIoC container to a default convention mapping (for example: resolve IFoo to Foo and IBar to Bar).

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: I cant find any such scenario in the documentation   https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RulesAndDefaultConventions#markdown-header-rules-and-default-conventions

Comment: According to this list it should be: http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison

Comment: You want to automatically register all types from given assembly?

Comment: I want the IoC container to resolve any implementation based on a naming convention. It should be able to find any implementation from the composition root as starting point.

Comment: So to clarify, if class Foo implements IFoo - you want it to be registered and resolve. But if Bar implements something other than IBar (IService) - it should not be registered and resolvable.

Comment: try something like this container.RegisterMany(AssemblySource.Instance,
    serviceTypeCondition: type =>  type.Name.Equals( type.GetInterface("I" + type.Name).Name ) );

Comment: Does it mean FooBar should not be resolved?

Comment: WithAutoFallbackResolution may be also your choice, or just check how it is implemented - just a sugar on top of WithUnknownServiceResolvers. But I would suggest to be more explicit with RegisterMany.